# media element.js audio setup fails in firefox, works everywhere else

Tags: firefox, audio, mediaelement.js

I'm using media element to play some audio.  The setup I have works in everything except firefox and I can't seem to figure out why.

Thanks so much for any help with this.

Here's how I have it set up:

```
<div id="audio-container">    
    <audio id="player2" src="audio/budget_1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"    preload="auto">        
    </audio>
</div>


<script>
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.play();
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {

            if ($("#main-container").hasClass("intro")) {
                $("#modal-fader").fadeOut(300);
                $("#modal-wrapper").animate({
                    marginTop: -412
               }, 300);
                mediaElement.setSrc("audio/budget_2.mp3");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    mediaElement.play();
                },1000);
                $("#main-container").removeClass("intro");
            } else {
                $("#cover").css({
                    display:"none"
                });
                $("#modal-closer").css({display:"block"});
            }
        }, true);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not natively support MP3. In order for it to work you must:

- Have a third-party decoder installed (usually true for OSX, Windows, often not true for Linux/BSD)
- Have a recent-enough Firefox build that brings said platform support. IIRC, the current Firefox release version (Firefox 23) does not support playback on platforms other than Windows 7 and maybe Windows Vista and Android. Future versions will enable XP, OSX and *nix (gstreamer).

You can use opus, ogg or wav codecs in current Firefox releases. See the [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) on how to provide different codec options in a single `<audio>` element.